# Update Gridview Based on a View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I'm creating an application in work that will allow customers to update a target per hour for a specific item which is split into different categories. Each category also has a process (they all have the same nine processes).

I've been working on this for a few days now and can't come up with a feasible solution to the problem. My latest attempt is splitting it all into different tables with complicated links that creates one single view.

I now want to be able to update the specific main table with the new values. Although, as the Gridview is based on a view I have no idea how to do this.

I'm not asking for tutorials, and I'm not breaking rules asking for a solution to my problem. I've also tried various different attempts at this problem. Simply asking for some guideance.

Comment: You can select from a view but update a table if you customize the GridView's DataSource. Assuming the GridView is bound to a SqlDataSource these would be the SelectCommand and UpdateCommand, Include them in your post. If you're not using a SqlDataSource post the GridView code and then whatever code you are using to populate the GridView .